# Precedence when using `or` vs `||` in Ruby `reject` block

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
[1].reject{|n| [].include? n or n == 1} # => [] 
[1].reject{|n| [].include? n || n == 1} # => [1]
```

I am not sure what it means for `||` to have higher precedence, or why it would affect this outcome.

Comment: When in doubt, just use the parentheses.

Comment: Use `or` for control flow, `||` for conditions. And yes: use parentheses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is due to their precedence relative to the `#include?` method call without parentheses.

`or` binds *less* tightly (has lower precedence, i.e. evaluates later) than the method call `.include? n`, and so the expression evaluates as `([].include? n) or (n == 1) #=> true`

`||`, on the other hand, binds *more* tightly (has higher precedence, i.e. evaluates earlier) than the method call, and so the expression evaluates as `[].include?((n || (n == 1))) #=> false`.

Precedence refers to the order of operations. It's like in algebra class when you learned **PEMDAS**:

- parentheses,
- exponentiation,
- multiplication/division,
- addition/subtraction.

Programming languages, like mathematical notation, have to obey a specific order of operations in order to evaluate non-ambiguously. In Ruby, for the operations you have here, it goes:

- `||`,
- method call,
- `or`.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed due to precedence and parenthesis will (hopefully) help clarify things.

These two lines are equivalent:

```
[1] pry(main)> [1].reject{|n| [].include? n or n == 1}
=> []
[2] pry(main)> [1].reject{|n| ([].include? n) or (n == 1)}
=> []
```

As are these:

```
[3] pry(main)> [1].reject{|n| [].include? n || n == 1}
=> [1]
[4] pry(main)> [1].reject{|n| [].include? (n || n == 1)}
=> [1]
```

Notice that in [4] the argument to `[].include?` is the result of evaluating the statement `n || n == 1`, which returns `true`. Since the empty array `[]` does not include `true` the block evaluates to `false` and the `n` is not rejected.

In [2], however, the argument passed to `[].include?` is just `n`. Since `n` is equal to `1` the block evaluates to `true` and `n` is indeed rejected. Note also that in [1] and [2] `n == 1` is never even executed.

So to get the `||` version to behave like the `or` version just do this:

```
[5] pry(main)> [1].reject{|n| ([].include? n) || (n == 1)}
=> []
```

Hopefully this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1].reject{|n| [].include? n || n == 1}
```

In above example as `||` has higher precedence `n || n` will execute and then `.include?`. So output is `[1]`.

```
[1].reject{|n| [].include? n or n == 1}
```

In above example `.include?` will execute w.r.t `n`. So output is `[]`.

If you would like to execute `n or n` first then use this:

```
[1].reject{|n| [].include? (n or n) == 1}
```

which will give output `[1]`.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want to execute `n or n`? Especially `[].include? (n or n) == 1`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Code obfuscation contest?